# How to create static string arrays and summonning them?

Tags: c, arrays, database, string

Trying to do hangman game and create my word database in beginning of the program.Then Summoning like str[i] with  rand func i int.

1. With Code in below it gives  INVALID CONVERSİON FROM CHAR TO CONSTANT CHAR

   ```
   char str[19];
   char temp[1000];
   char c[1];

   int ErrorCount=5;
   int i,j=0;

   i=rand()%19;

   str[0]="literature";
   str[1]="scholar";
   str[2]="enormous";
   str[3]="influence";
   str[4]="orchestra";
   str[5]="publication";
   str[6]="teacher";
   str[7]="member";
   str[8]="final";
   str[9]="phonograph";
   str[10]="striking";
   str[11]="different";
   str[12]="screwdriver";
   str[13]="intelligient";
   str[14]="executed";
   str[15]="oldest";
   str[16]="people";
   str[17]="requiring";
   str[18]="pioneer";
   str[19]="telephone";
   ```

Comment: You have an array of _characters_, not strings.

Comment: How can i make array of chars?

Comment: You already are. What you need is an array of char arrays. See my answer below again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char str[19];
```

The above statement defines `str` to be an array of `19` characters. In the following statement

```
str[0] = "literature";
```

the string literal `"literature"` evaluates to a pointer to its first element, which is of type `char *`. This pointer is assigned to `str[0]` which is of type `char`. This explains the error message you are getting. You should define `str` to be an array of pointers to characters. String literals are not const-qualified in `C`, therefore attempting to modify them won't result in compile error but undefined behaviour and most likely program crash. Therefore, `str` should be defined as an array of pointers to constant objects.

```
const char *str[19];
str[0] = "literature";
```

If you want to copy the string literals to your array, then you should define `str` as an array of character arrays. Later, you can use the standard library function `strcpy` to copy the string literals.

```
#define MAX_LEN 50+1  // +1 for the terminating null byte

char strlist[19][MAX_LEN];

strcpy(strlist[0], "literature");
```

Answer (score 0):

With this:

```
char str[20];
```

you declare an array of characters, not "strings", which are character arrays in C. That is, to store an array of multiple strings like that, you need a 2d array of chars, so something like:

```
char str[20][100];
```

The above will create a 2d array in which you could hold 20 99 character-long arrays ("strings"), with the null terminator at the end of each.

If you want to be able to have arbitrarily long strings (the second dimension of your 2d `char` array), you can have an array of `char *`

```
char *[20];
```

You can then initialize each "string" as:

```
str[0]="literature";
str[1]="scholar";
str[2]="enormous";
str[3]="influence";
str[4]="orchestra";
str[5]="publication";
str[6]="teacher";
str[7]="member";
str[8]="final";
str[9]="phonograph";
str[10]="striking";
str[11]="different";
str[12]="screwdriver";
str[13]="intelligient";
str[14]="executed";
str[15]="oldest";
str[16]="people";
str[17]="requiring";
str[18]="pioneer";
str[19]="telephone";
```

Comment: How can i do that?Making array of chars?

Comment: If i make like str1[1000]="literature" i can't call like str**i**

Comment: Now it gives error incompitable assingment of const char[11]to char [100].Why it still gives error?

Comment: I think you have a typo in `char *[20];`. Should be `char *str[20];`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you try to assign strings, i.e. arrays of chars, to array entries of type char. Since you want to use your array as database, you could define and initialise the array in one go:

```
const char *words[20] = {
    "literature", "scholar", "enormous", "influence", "orchestra",
    "publication", "teacher", "member", "final", "phonograph",
    "striking", "different", "screwdriver", "intelligient",
    "executed", "oldest", "people", "requiring", "pioneer",
    "telephone"
};
```

The words in this array are string literals of type `const char *`; they are immutable. If you want to work on them, you must make a copy first, perhaps by `strcpy`'ing the chars to a local char buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have dealt with the specific problem of the misdeclaration of `str`, but you might also consider:

```
const char* str[] = {
    "literature",
    "scholar",
    "enormous",
    /* ... */
    "requiring",
    "pioneer",
    "telephone"
};

const size_t n_str = sizeof(str)/sizeof(char *);

/* etc. etc. */

i = rand() % n_str;
```

This has the advantage of eliminating both the magic number `19` and the list with literal indices. This makes adding and removing words from `str` much less error prone.